# How to Override superclass property value using a bespoke implementation?

Tags: c#

I have a superclass "Entity" in a logic-tier project within existing 3-tier "core" application code, from which 2 concrete classes "RiskEntity" and "PolicyEntity" inherit (in that same core project). The superclass possesses a public property "Loss" which is not overridden by the 2 subclasses. This property is used by other code within this core project. The implementation of that property refers to other classes/properties within that core project.

For a particular use case, I require the propery's getter to be implemented differently. If possible, I'd like that bespoke implementation to exist outside of the "core" C# project mentioned above, and I'd like the application to be configurable so as to instruct it to use that bespoke implementation whenever that property is referenced from within my core project.

Can anyone point me to an elegant pattern/technique to achieve this? I've wondered about using a helper interface within the getter, and using reflection to instantiate the correct implementation of that interface, based on (say) a project setting. But even if this is along the right lines, I'm not sure how the bespoke implementation could live outside of the core project code.

Alternative suggestions also welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is the property virtual?  Is the property defined in an interface?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't/don't want to do this with standard polymorphism?

Comment: @Charles - well the "standard" behaviour is as implemented. The bespoke behaviour is seen as more of a bolt-on, so ideally that bespoke code wouldn't exist in the core project. The super/sub-class structure is still apropriate. It's not really a third sub-class that I'm after, more a replacement implementation of the superclass getter. If what I've tried to describe can be achieved with standard polymorphism...I'm still trying to think how.

Comment: I'll try to reword/simplify this question. I think it comes down to this: I have a core C# middle-tier project containing all the code necessary to run the (3-tier) application in a standard mode. For a particular scenario, I need to use all the code/classes in that C# project, but with the implementation of just one or two methods altered. I don't want to add that bespoke code to my core project, nor do I want to duplicate/branch the whole project, just for that bespoke release. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the superclass? That is, can you insert some logic into the superclass constructor (and/or the Loss property) and re-deploy the assembly?

Comment: @Jay Elston - yes, I have access to the superclass, although these objects currently are constructed deep inside core processing (rather than, for example, being constructed in/from a GUI).

Comment: Thanks all for the comments / answers. I'm going to experiment and hopefully then I'll mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are describing having different implementations of how the `Loss` property is calculated this suggests to me the **Strategy** pattern. You can ensure that the base `Entity` class uses the default implementation but that the `Entity` sub-classes can be constructed using alternative replacement implementations. I would therefore start by defining an interface in your core project that can be implemented in assemblies outside the core assembly provided they have a reference to it. There's numerous variations on this theme and knowing which fits your situation is difficult to know precisely without seeing more of the code but the following gives a broad outline.

First, the Strategy interface and default implementation in your core project:

```
public interface ILossCalculator
{
   decimal CalculateLoss(); //maybe needs parameters, perhaps even the Entity itself?
}

public class DefaultLossCalculator : ILossCalculator
{
   public DefaultLossCalculator(Dependency a, OtherDependency b)
   {
       //just an example, but here we inject the other classes that the 
       //default implementation requires to do the calculation.
   }

   public decimal CalculateLoss()
   {
       //default implementation ...
       return totalLoss;
   }
}
```

Next, the `Entity` class and derived classes, again in the core project.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
   private ILossCalculator _lossCalculator;

   protected Entity(Dependency a, OtherDependency b)
   {
       _lossCalculator = new DefaultLossCalculator(a, b);
   }

   protected Entity(ILossCalculator lossCalculator)
   {
       _lossCalculator = lossCalculator;
   }

   public decimal Loss
   {
      get
      {
         return _lossCalculator.CalculateLoss();
      }
   }
}

public class RiskEntity : Entity
{
    public RiskEntity(Dependency a, Dependency b) : base(a, b)
    {
    }

    public RiskEntity(ILossCalculator lossCalculator) : base(lossCalculator)
    {
    }

    //rest of implementation
}

//Other derived class(es) omitted - you get the idea, though...
```

The client code that constructs the `Entity` derived objects can now push in different implementations of the `ILossCalculator` interface, even when the implementation is defined outside the core project. To achieve selecting the `ILossCalculator` implementation to use from configuration I would probably create a `Factory` that you would use to construct `Entity` subclasses which could be configured so that when an `Entity` gets created it would use a custom implementation of the `ILossCalculator`. The client's view would be something like:

```
var factory = new EntityFactory();
factory.LossCalculationStrategy(() => new MyCustomLossCalculator());

var entity = factory.CreateRiskEntity(); //returns a RiskEntity constructed with the custom loss calculator
```

Comment: This brought me very close to what I wanted. The main difference in my implementation is that the factory looks at config settings and uses reflection (Assembly.LoadFrom and then Assembly.CreateInstance) to instantiate the required ILossCalculator instance. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements very well, but it sounds very much like a good task for an inversion of control (IOC) framework.  My team uses Castle Windsor for IOC.

In brief, the framework allows you to configure a repository to return an object of type `X` to fulfill a request for an object of type `Y` (where X implements or inherits from Y).  You can define this association in code or in a .config file, which should meet your "I'd like the application to be configurable" requirement.

Depending on the difference you require in the property's getter, you can use a decorator (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to wrap the object or perhaps a subclass with a copy constructor.  The "prefer composition" guideline would favor the decorator.  I would only look at the subclass option if you need access to protected members in your bespoke implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've accepted the other answer but your second paragraph in particular is spot on for what I needed. We may adopt something like Castle Windsor if there are more cases to use this (we may need more "plug-in" behaviour in future), but at the moment I'm injecting the dependency pretty much as per the other answer.